# How to find matrix of representation in new bases if it's non-square?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am given the linear operator L: *$R^3 → R^2 $*

$L((x,y,z)) = (3y + 2z, 4x - 7y)$

I need to find its matrix in bases

$B = {(-5, -3, -2); (3, 0, 1); (5, 2, 2)}$ and $ C = {(4,3); (-3,-2)}$

The matrix of an operator, as far as I understand, is 
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 3 & 2 \\
    4 & -7 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
but how can I find it in new bases? It looks like I can't use the formula with transition matrices, since matrix is non-square and multiplication can't be performed. Unfortunately, I struggle to understand what is required to solve this problem.

Comment: You can use those formulas that you’ve learned by rote if you keep in mind that the input and output bases don’t have to be the same. Think of it in terms of converting the bases of the input and output _vectors_ to the transformation into the ones that the matrix wants, as Aleksejs Fomins describes in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say $u \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and $L$ is the operator matrix, as you have written above. Then

$$v = Lu$$

We can convert the problem to a different basis. In particular, we start by converting the original vectors into their corresponding new bases

$$u' = Bu; \; \; \; v' = Cv$$

We can subsititute the expressions for $u$ and $v$ into the map equation to get

$$v' = CLB^{-1} u' = L' u'$$

So $L' = CLB^{-1}$